# ansible, playbook don't setting dictionaries in env of docker_container when combine it

Tags: ansible, docker-container

I have two dict like secrets vault but in docker_container task does not get set correctly, only in debug -> msg does it right.

```
  - name: "loop combine"
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ item.key }} = {{ item.value }}"
    with_dict: "{{ names | combine(applications, recursive=True) }}"

Output
ok: [IP] => (item={u'key': u'baz', u'value': 4}) => {
    "msg": "baz = 4"
}

  - name: Start a container with a command
    docker_container:
      name: spring-prometheus
      image: "dockehub/my-image:v1"
      command: ["sleep", "infinity"]
      env:
        "{{ item|default({'key':'value'}) }}"
      ports:
        - "8081:8081"
    with_dict: "{{ names | combine(applications, recursive=True) }}"

- docker exec -it 9130976decaf env

   key=bar
   value=3
   ...
```

- but i put only

  with_dict: "{{ names }}" # it's correct
  bar=3
  ...

Comment: Do you really want to start the same container for every key/value in your dict, crushing the preceding one an only keeping the last ? Besides this rhetoric question, it would help to see the content of `names` and `applications` in your question.

Comment: it's a loop, it put all variable, not overwrite previous

name are look like 
APP_NAME: app
OTHER_SERVICE_NAME: app

and applications are secret vault
RABBIT_PASSWORD: xxx
OTHER_PASS: xxx

Comment: Yes it's a loop. So if you have 100 k/v in you loop, you will overwrite 99 times the same container keeping only the last one with the last k/v in your environment.